# Need row id not to allow users to click on it if a status is not Received

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get it so that the record does not allow the user to update, when the row 'status' says Completed or In_Progress. Not sure how to accomplish this. Basically they can only click on the id which is linked to update_id.php only if the row status = Received. If it is Completed or In_progress they get pop-up box saying a custom error message. I am looking for an example or tutorial.

```
  <?php

        require_once 'db_connect.php';
        $conn = dbConnect();
        $OK = true; // We use this to verify the status of the update.
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            // Create the query
            $data = "%".$_GET['id']."%";
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM requests WHERE id like ?';
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $results = $stmt->execute(array($data));
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
            $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
            //echo $error[2];
        }
        // If there are no records.
        if(empty($rows)) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td colspan='4'>There were not records</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        else {
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                echo "<tr>";
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    echo "<td><a href='update_Id.php?id=$id'>$id</a></td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['lanId']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['department']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['mgrname']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['work_requested']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['purchase_order']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['inbound_shipment']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['status']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['request_comments']."</td>";


                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

update page

```
<?php
    include('../db_connect.php');
    include('../functions/functions.php');
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE id= :id");
    $result->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/textboxname_autocomplete2.js"></script>

<title></title>

<style type="text/css">

}
.body{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border: thin solid #666666;
}
</style>

</head>
<body class='body'>
<form action = "update_Id_Process.php"  method ="post" class="Form">

<p><input type ="hidden" name = "id" value="<?php echo($id); ?>"</p>

<h2 align="center">Edit request  Information</h2>
<table border='1' align="center" style="width: 582px">

<tr>    
    <td>Employee Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['name']) ?>"name="name"></td>

    <td>Manager Name</td>
<td style="width: 175px">
<input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['mgrname']) ?>"name="mgrname" style="width: 162px"></td>
</tr>


<tr>    
    <td>Employee Lan Id:</td>
<td><input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['lanId']) ?>"name="lanId"></td>

    <td>Manger_LanId</td>
<td style="width: 175px">
<input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['mgrLanId']) ?>"name="mgrLanId" style="width: 162px"></td>
</tr>

<tr>    
    <td>Department Location</td>
<td><input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['department']) ?>"name="department"></td>

    <td>PO</td>
<td style="width: 175px">
<input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['purchase_order']) ?>"name="purchase_order" style="width: 162px"></td>
</tr>


<tr>    
    <td>Work Requested</td>
<td><input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['work_requested']) ?>"name="work_requested"></td>
    <td>IS</td>
<td style="width: 175px">
<input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['inbound_shipment']) ?>"name="inbound_shipment" style="width: 162px"></td>
</tr>

</table>
<h2 align='center'>Requested Comments</h2>
<table border='1' align="center">


<tr>    

<td width='400'  height="40">
<textarea name="request_comments"  style="width: 600px; height: 81px" style="text-transform:uppercase ;"><?php echo $row['request_comments']; ?></textarea></td>

</tr>

</table>
<input type="hidden" value ="<?php  echo($row['status']) ?>"name="status">
<input type="hidden" value ="<?php  echo($row['comments']) ?>"name="comments">
<input type="hidden" value ="<?php  echo($row['compUser']) ?>"name="compUser">
<input type="hidden" value ="<?php  echo($row['compDt']) ?>"name="compDt">
    <br>
<div align="center">    
<input type="submit" value= "Update Information">
<br>
</div>
</form>


</body>
</html>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: `if($row['status'] == "something"){ // do something }`

Comment: Thank you I will try to figure it out and see what I get.

Comment: You're welcome Donny. You can put that in your `foreach` loop. Although, I tend to think that it may work better in a `while` loop, but I could be wrong. Try it out and see, it should work.

Comment: I tried it but now the record is not showing up maybe I am still confused. I will have to keep playing around with it till it works and check the error log.

Comment: I'd try a `while($row...` instead of a `foreach` then, and inside do the `if($row...`.

Comment: I will try that also I was thinking going another route. when I click the id it takes me to an update page maybe I can write a java-script that if the text-box with the posted data says completed or in-progress user can't update the information. I can post the code above with the update page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to create a javascript to disable the button if the word completed or In_progress was posted back in the text-box of the update page. Also it will alert the user that they could not update without the status textbox saying received.

Here is the update page revised for others to see how its done.

```
 <?php
            include('../db_connect.php');
            include('../functions/functions.php');
            $id=$_GET['id'];
            $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE id= :id");
            $result->bindParam(':id', $id);
            $result->execute();
            for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
        ?>

        <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/textboxname_autocomplete2.js"></script>

        <title></title>

        <style type="text/css">

        }
        .body{
            background-color: #F2F2F2;
            border: thin solid #666666;
        }

        </style>


        <script type="text/javascript">

        function NoWord(el){

        var subb=document.forms[0].elements["status"].value;

        if(subb=="Completed" || subb=="In_Progress")
        {
        alert("Can only update request when in Received Status");
        document.forms[0].elements["button1"].disabled="disabled"
        window.location.href="http://google.com";
            return false;

        }

        return true;
        }

        </script>

        </head>
        <body class='body'>
        <form name="myForm" action="update_Id_Process.php"  method="post" class="Form" onsubmit="return NoWord(this.name);">

        <p><input type ="hidden" name = "id" value="<?php echo($id); ?>"</p>

        <h2 align="center">Edit request  Information</h2>
        <table border='1' align="center" style="width: 582px">

        <tr>    
            <td>Employee Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['name']) ?>"name="name"></td>

            <td>Manager Name</td>
        <td style="width: 175px">
        <input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['mgrname']) ?>"name="mgrname" style="width: 162px"></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>    
            <td>Employee Lan Id:</td>
        <td><input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['lanId']) ?>"name="lanId"></td>

            <td>Manger_LanId</td>
        <td style="width: 175px">
        <input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['mgrLanId']) ?>"name="mgrLanId" style="width: 162px"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>    
            <td>Department Location</td>
        <td><input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['department']) ?>"name="department"></td>

            <td>PO</td>
        <td style="width: 175px">
        <input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['purchase_order']) ?>"name="purchase_order" style="width: 162px"></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>    
            <td>Work Requested</td>
        <td><input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['work_requested']) ?>"name="work_requested"></td>
            <td>IS</td>
        <td style="width: 175px">
        <input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['inbound_shipment']) ?>"name="inbound_shipment" style="width: 162px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Status</td>
        <td><input type="text" value ="<?php  echo($row['status']) ?>" id="status"  name="status"></td>
            <td></td>
        <td style="width: 175px"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <h2 align='center'>Requested Comments</h2>
        <table border='1' align="center">


        <tr>    

        <td width='400'  height="40">
        <textarea name="request_comments"  style="width: 600px; height: 81px" style="text-transform:uppercase ;"><?php echo $row['request_comments']; ?></textarea></td>

        </tr>

        </table>

        <input type="hidden" value ="<?php  echo($row['comments']) ?>" name="comments">
        <input type="hidden" value ="<?php  echo($row['compUser']) ?>" name="compUser">
        <input type="hidden" value ="<?php  echo($row['compDt']) ?>" name="compDt">
            <br>

        <div align="center"><input type="submit" value="Update Information" name="button1"></dv>

        </form>


        </body>
        </html>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
```